# Can PDO statements be nulled inside a transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I know this is probably a little bit weird question, but basically the case is this:

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('...');
$stmt->bindValue(':something', $something);
if (!$stmt->execute()) { $pdo->rollBack(); }
$stmt = null;

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('...');
$stmt->bindValue(':something', $something);
if (!$stmt->execute()) { $pdo->rollBack(); }
$stmt = null;

$pdo->commit();
```

I guess the question moreso is whether the `$stmt`s have to exist at the time of the rollback/commit or whether the rollback is executed purely on database level and it doesn't matter.

Could some random failures on this be attributed to `gc` cleaning up the statements before the `commit`? Also, would the situation change without the latter rollback - i.e. if the second statement failure would not constitute a rollBack?

Notice! I am looking to understand the process on a low level. I am perfectly aware that the statements could be in separate variables and cleaned up after the transaction commit. :)

Comment: Rollback is operates on the database, it has nothing to do with PDO.

Comment: Could you explain the "random failures" you think you're seeing?

Comment: There's basically a lot of traffic and I see results of the second query being applied, but the process simply dying without a trace. I am fairly confident that this is the place where i breaks, but am willing to believe otherwise. I also found this that suggests that the commit can't be trusted with MySQL which is the database running here. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66528

Comment: One problem I see is that if the first statement fails you roll back the transaction. Then you continue running without starting a new transaction.

Comment: Maybe you didn't realize that rolling back ends the transaction, it doesn't just undo the actions that have taken place so far.

Comment: Ahh yes, that is my bad. The original code does not continue on failure. I'm specifically looking into the processes mysteriously dying after the second statement has been successfully executed (i.e. the change appears in the database).

Comment: That seems unrelated, since it's happening after the transaction is committed.